AttributeError when setting an attribute into a private one
class Topping:
    def __init__(self, topping_type: str, weight: float):
        self.topping_type = topping_type
        self.weight = weight
        
    @property
    def topping_type(self):
        return self.__topping_type
        
    @topping_type.setter
    def topping_type(self, value):
        if self.topping_type == "":
            raise ValueError("The topping type cannot be an empty string")
        self.__topping_type = value
    
    @property
    def weight(self):
        return self.__weight
    
    @weight.setter
    def weight(self, value):
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError("The weight cannot be less or equal to zero")
        self.__weight = value

AttributeError: 'Topping' object has no attribute '_Topping__topping_type'

Why do I get that error? My understanding is that I'm making self.topping_type into a private attribute with the setters and getters but I'm guessing it's wrong.

Please always provide the full error message including the stack trace. The Python runtime goes to great lengths to provide you with that precisely because it is helpful for debugging errors... Why would you omit it?

Your setter is checking the attribute (which hasn't been set yet), rather than its argument.
@topping_type.setter
def topping_type(self, value):
    if value == "":
        raise ValueError("The topping type cannot be an empty string")
    self.__topping_type = value

